# ReactJS: How can I update state of property using localStorage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I have a [component](https://github.com/mohitk05/react-insta-stories/blob/ec2c06e94917e58163b072e17e9821bcf69874bf/src/components/Container.js) with the following initial state:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      currentId: 0,
      pause: true,
      count: 0,
      storiesDone: 0
    }
    this.defaultInterval = 4000
    this.width = props.width || 360
    this.height = props.height || 640
  }
```

I have to start from `currentId = 0` and then update the state of the component, even after a page refresh.

I want to restore `currentId = 1` after persisting a value of `1`.

I am getting an error that the property cannot change , when I try replacing `currentId = localStorage.getItem('currentId')` in the above code.

```
    var currentId = this.state.currentId;    
      localStorage.setItem( 'currentId', 1);
      console.log(currentId);
      localStorage.getItem('currentId');
```

I also tried:

```
  _this.setState((state) => {
      return {currentId: localStorage.getItem('currentId')};
    });
```

Comment: just setup the default state definition in your constructor to use the localstorage values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value type persisted to `localStorage` [must be a string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

Consider revising the code that interacts with `localStorage` so that the state value `currentId` is first converted to a string before it is passed to `localStorage.setItem()`.

Also note that [string values are returned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem) by `localStorage.getItem()` when a key is present, which means you should parse the returned value to obtain `currentId` as a number.

Something along the lines of this should work:

```
const saveCurrentId = () => {    

    const { currentId } = this.state;    

    /* Format string from value of currentId and persist */
    localStorage.setItem( 'currentId', `${ currentId }`);
}

const loadCurrentId = (fallbackValue) => {

    /* Load currentId value from localStorage and parse to integer */
    const currentId = Number.parseInt(localStorage.getItem('currentId'));

    /* Return currentId if valid, otherwise return fallback value */
    return Number.isNaN(currentId) ? fallbackValue : currentId;
}
```

With the code above, you can then update your components constructor to automatically load and apply the persisted `currentId` as follows:

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {

      /* Use 0 as fallback if no persisted value present */
      currentId: this.loadCurrentId( 0 ), 

      pause: true,
      count: 0,
      storiesDone: 0
    }
    this.defaultInterval = 4000
    this.width = props.width || 360
    this.height = props.height || 640
  }
```

Comment: I am attempting this method, but it doesn't read from the console, i only see "null" .
when trying `localStorage.getItem('currentId')`. Thanks very much for the update . I will try the latest edit

Comment: @JonasKgomo you're welcome, let me know if you have any problems

Comment: Console says `saveCurrentId` is declared but never used , and `localStorage`still returns null. However, the second variable `loadcurrentId` applies well to the constructor.

Comment: @JonasKgomo glad to head `loadCurrentId()` works - how are you calling/using `saveCurrentId()`? something like this should work in say an onClick prop: `onClick = { () => this.saveCurrentId() }`

Comment: I would like it start when state changes(automatically), I mean when state changes from `0` to `1`, its my mistake, i didnt call it.

Comment: @JonasKgomo ok no problems - something else that might be useful to know is that you can update the data persisted with `localStorage` after a state change via the setState callback like this: `this.setState({ currentId : newValue }, () => { this.saveCurrentId() })`

Comment: It works almost like sacrosanct code, will thank you well when I am done

Answer (score 1):

Use componentDidMount. See the code below. I added checking if localStorage.currentId have value. If it have, check if the value from localStorage.currentId match state's currentId and if it don't then update the state to the value from localStorage.

```
state = {
  currentId: 0,
  pause: true,
  count: 0,
  storiesDone: 0
}
componentDidMount() {
  //Assign localStorage.get("currentId") to a variable
  const localCurrentId = localStorage.get("currentId");
  //Check if localCurrentId is not null or undefined
  if (localCurrentId) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      //Update state's currentId if the current value didn't match with localCurrentId
      currentId: prevState.currentId !== localCurrentId ? localCurrentId : prevState.currentId
    }));
  }
}
```